# Google Web Toolkit for a legacy project

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea, legacy, legacy-app

I am working in a legacy web application which means that the project structure is different than an ideal GWT project structure. I would like add GWT for it. I am using intellij as the IDE. Any suggestion or link to any tutorial is highly appreciated.

P.S. I followed this link...but it's is not so helpful. 
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/adding-a-gwt-facet-to-a-module.html

Comment: In general: yes, GWT can be integrated with legacy software. But without more concrete explanations about your use-case, you won't get a really helpful answer. Some questions you could answer: What is the actual structure of your application? Which technologies do you use? Which build tool is used? Do you plan a migration to GWT or simply implement new features with GWT and don't touch the legacy code?

Comment: Thanks. Answers are: 
1. Project Structure: http://imgur.com/2U7O8ss
2. Mostly core java, jsp, js and jquery
3. No..I am not using any build tool.
4. There are some pop ups in the legacy systems which I want to implement with GWT. So, total migration is not under consideration

Comment: @SteffenSchäfer...should I share any more information?